# What is the Pythonic way to use a default value when function returns None or throws exception?

Tags: python, exception, default-value, nonetype

What's a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
try:
    a = foo() or b
except AttributeError:
    a = b
```

I want to set `a` to be the return of the function `foo`, but if `foo` returns `None` or an `AttributeError` exception is raised, then I want `a` to be set to `b`.

Comment: It's "Pythonic" enough.

Comment: What if `foo` returns `0`?

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, you could perhaps use a decorator on `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as pointed out by Gennady Kandaurov: you'd need to test for 'valid' return values of `foo()` that are not 'truthy' (as `0`, `[]`, `()`, ...):

```
try:
    a = foo() if foo() is not None else b
except AttributeError:
    a = b
```

depending on the implementation details of `foo` (whether it is expensive or has side-effects) you may want to call it once only:

```
try:
    f = foo()
    a = f if f is not None else b
except AttributeError:
    a = b
```

Comment: This calls the function `foo` twice, which may or may not be okay.

Comment: What if `foo` is expensive to call?

Comment: yup, thougt of that as well.

Comment: @PeterWood or has side effects!!